# which plants is it? small in size, long thin leaves

Tags: identification

which plants is it? My mumma says it's a tree. Please help me identify.

I've this plant from over one year now. This plant came randomly, I think because of birds might have bought the seed of this. In one entire year this plant has only grown this much.

But the base steam is very strong, in a very windy condition only leaves wave with breeze, plant is stiff at its position.

If this plant is a tree, can I bonsai?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Looks like an avocado-tree to my eyes.

Answer (score 0):

Not so sure but at first sight it looks like *[Polyalthia longifolia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyalthia_longifolia)* to me.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please take some time to explain what characteristics of the plant in the photograph led you to that conclusion. Your answer would be much more helpful with that extra information.